# ¿Cómo pasar datos de una app WPF a una app de consola C#?

Tags: c#, proceso

Tengo una aplicación de consola a la cual quiero pasarle unos datos desde una aplicación WPF.
Actualmente estaba utilizando el siguiente comando para pasarle un fichero:

`Process.Start("Aplicacion.exe",Fichero);`

Este fichero lo leo en el Main de la app de consola como args[0]
Ahora quiero pasarle a parte del fichero, dos strings pero me está dando error al intentar pasarlos como:

`Process.Start("Aplicacion.exe",Fichero, string1,...);`

Si alguien puede ayudarme se agradece!

Comment: Los argumentos en principio se pasan separados por espacios. Asi que tendrías que usar algo como `Process.Start("Aplicacion.exe",Fichero + " " +  string1 + " " + string2);`

Comment: Que tipo de datos es la variable fichero?